# socket slows down receiving in sleep mode

Tags: android, sockets

I am using sockets to receive data, It starts receiving data but as phones goes in sleep mode, it gradually slow down and ultimately it slow down to socket timeout.
To prevent this situation I am using Wake locks, but it still do not show any benefit.
Anyone have idea ?